# I just assembled my computer and the motherboard started smoking, how do I know which parts are affected?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

I was changing my desktop case and after I got all parts together and turned it on, the motherboard started smoking next to the 4-pin power cable (the one that provides power to the processor). I'm not sure which power suply cable actually started smoking because I turned it off really quick.

Im puzzled because the power supply pins are built in such a way that's nearly impossible to connect anything wrong, and it's not the first time I do it, I'm not unexperienced. I suspect one of the parts where not working properly, and that caused some sort of short circuit.

Now my question is: How do I know which are the parts affected so I can replace them?

I suspect the motherboard, the power supply and the processor may not work anymore, but it's just my guess.

What do I do?

Comment: check the motherboard isn't shorted on the case. Like say if a screw got dropped during putting together and wedged behind the board and the case. -- I have done this, it sucked. (and it was subsequently permanently broken)

Comment: Oh dear... I'd start with eyeball mk1 and the sniff test. There's usually some burn damage when the magic smoke escapes.

Comment: Can you get it to the point where it will boot up a diagnostic system.  There are plenty available which will go through your system and do hardware checks, not using Windows or Linux.